# Issues with creation/running playn 1.3.1/1.4 projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, playn

When I try running showcase sample via maven (using "mvn test" and "mvn test -Ptest-java") I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR]    
[ERROR] The project com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase:1.0-SNAPSHOT (E:\Desarrollo\Git\playn-samples\showcase\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.googlecode.playn:playn-project:pom:1.4-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]    
[ERROR]    
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.   
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I can create projects via Maven but when I try to create a new playn 1.3.1 project via Eclipse I get:

```
'Creating playn-archetype' has encountered a problem.

Unable to create project from archetype
[com.googlecode.playn:playn-archetype:1.3.1]

Details: Unable to create project from archetype [com.googlecode.playn:playn-archetype:1.3.1]
The defined artifact is not an archetype
```

(The same happens with playn 1.4)

When I try to import a playn 1.3.1 or 1.4 project to Eclipse (created via Maven) I get the next error:

```
'Importing Maven projects' has encountered a problem.
An internal error ocurred during: "Importing Maven projects".

Details: An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
com/android/io/StreamException
```

So I cannot run any project via Eclipse.

I use Eclipse Indigo 3.7, maven 3.0.4 and JDK 7u5; and I follow all the steps that shows playn getting started.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to this bug: https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/89

You might try the master update site (http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/updates/master/), till the new version is released from m2e-android.

Comment: It seems that with the new release of m2e-android this kind of error has disappeared, it compiles fine.